# Increase Request timeout asp.net and WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an ASP.net application which calls a WCF service to retrieve Data from SQL Server.

There is a function which has to wait the WCF to Select some rows from over 1 million records. This function causes my ASP application to generate a Request timeout error.
I used the following lines to increase the timeout but it did not work, I cannot edit the IIS config file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="500" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe timeouts that you are looking for are in binding configuration. If you get your data from wcf service then look for your endpoint config and configure binding for it.
look below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" 
             closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks